# Subscribe from another website to the same list

Tags: email, subscription, newsletter

I am using Email Subscribers and newsletters 1.0 plugin in wordpress 4.7.2
I created a daughter website and wanted to subscribe to the same subscribe list.
How will this be done?
I could not find something similar to a mailchimp action url which I can enter anywhere.